# Build libcrypto with -fPIC

Tags: make, openssl

I am trying to build [Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia) from source, but running `make` returns this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(poly1305-x86_64.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `poly1305_blocks' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

I got a similar error with libssl, so I added -fPIC to `openssl` `Makefile`. But after getting the same error with libcrypto, I added -fPIC to the `crypto` `Makefile`, and built openssl from source again. But I cannot get past this error.

How do I get libcrypto rebuilt with -fPIC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't feel bad, it's a bug in OpenSSL! I found it when trying to use OpenSSL as a shared library, hope this fix helps :)

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/744

**dot-asm commented on 26 Feb**

Somewhere in the beginning of crypto/poly1305/asm/poly1305-x86_64.pl you can find

```
.globl  poly1305_init
.globl  poly1305_blocks
.globl  poly1305_emit
```

Adding following lines should help

```
.hidden poly1305_blocks
.hidden poly1305_emit
```

Test and report back.

Comment: Yes, it works. I did the same thing, just forgot to update my question.